# Change a key in a Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update a key from "new" to "1". How can I do this ?

Old One:

```
Map<String, String> titleTextFieldList = {"new":"title"};
```

What I want:

```
{"1":"title"}
```

Comment: can't you remove and add a new one without replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look. You can do it create a new map and checking the key if it matches then replacing it with another key.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, String> titleTextFieldList = {"new": "title", "test": "test"};
  Map<String, String> newMap = {};

  titleTextFieldList.forEach((i, value) {
    if (i == "new") {
      newMap["1"] = value;
    } else {
      newMap.addAll({"$i": "$value"});
    }
  });

  print(newMap); //{1: title, test: test}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as the @rosh-dev state.

```
Map<String, String> titleTextFieldList = {"new":"title"};
```

```
Map<String, String> titleTextFieldList2 ={"1": titleTextFieldList['new']}
print('$titleTextFieldList2');
```

Comment: you need to check the key. if the `new` key does not exist what you will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() { 
  Map<String, String> titleTextFieldList = {"new": "title","b":"kkk"};
  Map<String, String> newMap = {};

  int i = 1; 
  titleTextFieldList.keys.toList().forEach((key) { 
    newMap.addAll( {"${key=='new'?'1':key}": titleTextFieldList[key]}); i++; });

  print(titleTextFieldList); 
  print(newMap);
}
```

output is:

```
{"new": "title", "b": "kkk"}
{"1": "title", "b": "kkk"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a key name with a newer one you can create an extension on map:

```dart
extension MapExtension on Map<String, dynamic> {
  void changeKeyName(String oldKey, String key) {
    this[key] = this[oldKey];
    this.remove(oldKey);
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```dart
final map = data as Map<String, dynamic>;
map.changeKeyName('Order_status', 'status');
final order = Order.formJson(map);
...
```